# Left align column in align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I am trying to make a list of mathematical objects, and I've been using the align environment to do so. This is my code:

```
\begin{align*}
& \textit{Title1} & \textit{Title2 for the second column}\\
& \{entry\}  &  \{entry\}    \\
& \{entry number 2\}         &  \{yet another entry\} 
\end{align*}
```

It produces the following, and I would like the second column to be left aligned as well. I've tried flalign but that doesn't give the correct result either.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome  to TeX SX! Why don't you do that  with an `array` environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\begin{align*}
& \textit{Title1}    && \textit{Title2 for the second column}\\
& \{entry\}          &&  \{entry\}    \\
& \{entry number 2\} &&  \{yet another entry\} 
\end{align*}
```

You need `2n-1` `&`'s per line. One `&` per alignment point, and `n-1` to separate alignment columns. In this case `n=2` so you need 3 `&`'s. You only used 2 and thus you get

```
right aligned (empty) & left aligned & (separator) right aligned \\
```

you wanted

```
right aligned (empty) & left aligned & (separator) right aligned (empty) & left aligned
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!